# Grammar, Stack, Terminal-Symbols and Tokens

Tags: parsing, token, symbols

a parser (or compiler) usually comprises of a tokenizer, which recognizes certain token-types in the series of symbols from the alphabet which is the input.

Such that our parser only reads a stream of tokens. Not raw characters.

On a grammatical tier however, one speaks of Terminals and Nonterminals. But not tokens.

Which means that both the grammar and the stack (let's assume we are using a LL(k) or a LR-family parser) consist of Terminals and Nonterminals. But let's also assume that it makes sense, to use, likewise when speaking of symbols from a grammatical point of view, the token-types for terminal-symbols as well.

Is there a convention on how to represent grammar symbols (terminals, especially) and are the terminals normally "typed" ?

My guess would be multiple inheritance of interfaces - yet there is only one class TokenType, such that an interface wouldn't really make any sense. With IGrammarSymbol you have at least two classes, Terminal and Nonterminal, which can implement that interface.

Sincerely yours

Answer (score 2):

Every grammar symbol, terminal or non-terminal, is logically a (different) class in the parser. There is no inherent similarity between the different "terminal" classes or the different "non-terminal" classes, and grouping these classes into an inheritance structure derived from "terminal" and "non-terminal" base classes makes little sense.

Each concrete instance of a grammar symbol is associated with zero or more attributes. The semantics and types of the attributes are determined by the symbol's type. It can make sense to derive two different grammar symbol classes which happen to have the same (or similar) attribute collections from the same base type. For example, different kinds of expression-operator non-terminals may all be derived from some base `Expression` class. Value-carrying terminals (identifiers and literal constants) might also be derived from this class, but purely syntactic terminals are more likely to be derived from a class which has no semantics attributes. (It might still have syntactic attributes which correlate with the source code location. It might at first glance seem that these syntactic attributes only apply to terminals, but it is often convenient for non-terminals to also have syntactic attributes.)

Comment: So when the grammar derives a terminal of type IDENTIFIER or NUMBER - which can be multiple actual lexemes, this does not belong to syntax anymore but to semantics already?

Comment: @vonspotz: When it converts the string of characters which make up the NUMBER into an actual number, that is semantics. The grammar doesn't distinguish  between `3` and `42`, but there is obviously a (semantic) difference.

Comment: Yes, ok, at that point. And if you just specify in the grammar that the symbol the parser must read must be of type 'NUMBER' ? What is the convention? Is the RHS - except for 'Sum' which is a Nonterminal - of the following rule internally represented by 'class Terminal' or by 'class Token' ?

Sum ::= <NUMBER> <'+'> <NUMBER>
         | Sum <'+'> <NUMBER>

Comment: And if you consider the SymbolType / TokenType "keywords", then the attribute 'value' with possible values like "if", "else", "begin","end","do","while","for", etc. is not semantics.

Comment: @vonspotz: (1) There is no `class Token` nor `class Terminal`. There is a `class NUMBER` and a `class Sum` (which, as I said, probably inherits from `class Expression`). The number token is of class `NUMBER`, and the `Sum` rule (which is just `Sum ::= <NUMBER> | Sum <'+'> <NUMBER>`) produces an object of class `Expression`. At least, that's one common way of doing it.

Comment: (2) Keyword tokens don't have attributes. There is no `class Keyword` (except possibly as an abstract base class). There are classes `keyword_if`, `keyword_else`, etc. It is correct that these classes do not carry semantic values. The key insight is that the parse *only cares about the class*, not about the attributes (if any). Any examination of attributes is in the semantic analysis (or semantic rules).